# LINQ: Get sum from a list grouped by an inside list

Tags: c#, linq

There are similar questions but i couldn't found a solution. I've a very simple object definitions. I need a query that returns sum of the amount grouped by *Tags*.

Expected Output:

```
TagName         Sum
--------------------
Entertainment  70.00
Car            20.00
Travel         24.65
```

Account class:

```
public string AccountName {get;set;}
public List<Transaction> Transactions {get;set;}
```

*Sample Account*: My Wallet

Transaction class:

```
public decimal Amount {get;set;}
public List<Tag> Tags{get;set;}
```

*Sample Transaction*: `10 , [Entertainment, Travel, Car]`

Tag class

```
public string Title {get;set;}
```

*Sample Tag*: `Entertainment, Travel, Car, Food, Beverage`

I hope it's clear. I couldn't make it using **LINQ**. I need help

Answer (score 5):

Project each transaction into sequence of `{ Amount, Title }` objects. Than group these objects by tag and calculate sum of amounts for each group:

```
account.Transactions
       .SelectMany(t => t.Tags.Select(tag => new { t.Amount, tag.Title }))
       .GroupBy(tagAmount => tagAmount.Title)
       .Select(g => new {
          TagName = g.Key,
          Sum = g.Sum(tagAmount => tagAmount.Amount)
       });
```

NOTE: This solution assumes you don't have duplicate tags in transactions. Otherwise you should add `Distinct()` call after projecting tags collection.

---

Same with query syntax:

```
var query = from t in account.Transactions
            from tag in t.Tags
            select new { t.Amount, tag.Title } into tagAmount
            group tagAmount by tagAmount.Title into g
            select new
            {
                TagName = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(tagAmount => tagAmount.Amount)
            };
```

Comment: By the way can u suggest any resource to improve my linq skills.

Comment: @Murat you can find great intro to Linq on [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/linq-fundamentals) videos. Also there is reimplementing Linq series by Jon Skeet, which will explain you how Linq works inside. And then practice, practice, practice :)